# Problem running private Application with FFMPEG on Ubuntu 19

Tags: ffmpeg, opencv

I am facing the following error when running an application:

```
./Application: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54: version `LIBAVUTIL_FFMPEG_54' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.3)
./Application: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale-ffmpeg.so.3: version `LIBSWSCALE_FFMPEG_3' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.3)
./Application: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56: version `LIBAVCODEC_FFMPEG_56' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.3)
./Application: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56: version `LIBAVFORMAT_FFMPEG_56' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.3)
```

ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg version 4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1)
  configuration: --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

ldd $(which ffmpeg) seems to be ok:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc726da000)
libavdevice.so.58 => /usr/local/lib/libavdevice.so.58 (0x00007feed0645000)
libavfilter.so.7 => /usr/local/lib/libavfilter.so.7 (0x00007feed0374000)
libavformat.so.58 => /usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.58 (0x00007feed012a000)
libavcodec.so.58 => /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.58 (0x00007feecec71000)
libswresample.so.3 => /usr/local/lib/libswresample.so.3 (0x00007feecec53000)
libswscale.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/libswscale.so.5 (0x00007feecebc7000)
libavutil.so.56 => /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so.56 (0x00007feeceabd000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007feece96f000)
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007feece94e000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007feece763000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007feece73a000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007feece735000)
libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007feece72e000)
libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007feece724000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007feece708000)
liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007feece6e1000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007feed06ca000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007feece4dd000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007feece2d5000)
libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007feece2bb000)
librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007feece2b0000)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to workaround it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your application is old and is looking for a really old FFmpeg version.

Problems:

- The application is looking for the `.so` files in the wrong location. Your application is looking for `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54`, etc, but your FFmpeg likely only provides `/usr/local/lib/libavutil.so.56`.
- The application is looking for the wrong names. `libavutil-ffmpeg` is the old naming scheme used by the ffmpeg package in old Ubuntu versions.
- The application expects an older FFmpeg version. The `54` and `56` represent the major versions of each FFmpeg library. Major versions are not API compatible with each other. The application looks like it was written for the FFmpeg 2.8 release branch according to your major version numbers. This is very old. You compiled and installed FFmpeg 4.2. Either update the application code to use the FFmpeg 4.2 release branch, or install FFmpeg 2.8 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @llogan! It was ideed as you explain.

Solution: I removed all old library and have download exactly each .deb package of the required .lib from Ubuntu repository and installed them manually.